# Finding structures that are models

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, quantifiers

We got 3 formulae expressing that the predicate is reflexive, symmetrical but not transitive

$$F_1=\forall x P(x,x)  \\F_2 = \forall x \forall y (P(x,y)\to P(y,x))
 \\F_3=\forall x\forall y\forall z (P(x,y)\land P(y,z))\to P(x,z))$$

I wanted to start finding an interpretation which is a model for $F_1, F_2$ and not $F_3$

For $F_3$ to not be satisfied I would need to find a way to make $P(x,z)$ unsatisfiable, but I can't seem to find anything that would keep $P(x,x), P(x,y), P(y,x)$ and $P(y,z)$ satisfiable...

My biggest problem is dealing with the universal quantifiers.

Any hint or help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that you are looking for a relation that is reflexive and symmetric but not transitive.

Comment: Thank you you two, I initially thought about using $\mathcal I(P) =\{(m,n) \mid m\le n\}$, but does $\forall$ not interfere? Like in $F_2$ how can all $x\le y$ *and* $y \le x$ at the same time? Wouldn't that only work if it was $\forall x \exists y$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm sorry, but can you elaborate? 1) if that would work, that would make $F_3$ also satisfiable no? 2) My problem is I don't see how $\forall x\forall y ((x\le y)) \to (y \le x))$ works, doesn't that mean it would compare *all* possible $x$'s with all possible $y$'s ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, but my second question; doesn't $\forall x \forall y (...)$ mean "For all x, all the y are equal"? That's what's bugging me

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah!!! That makes ***much*** more sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{A} = (U_\mathcal{A}, I_\mathcal{A})$ be the structure whose domain is $U_\mathcal{A} = \{1,2,3\}$ and whose interpretation of the predicate symbol $P$ is $I_\mathcal{A}(P) = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,1), (2,3), (3,2)\}$. Then you can easily check that $\mathcal{A} \models F_1$ (i.e. the interpretation of $P$ in $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies reflexivity) and $\mathcal{A} \models F_2$ (i.e. the interpretation of $P$ in $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies symmetry) but $\mathcal{A} \models \lnot F_3$ (i.e. the interpretation of $P$ in $\mathcal{A}$ does not satisfy transitivity, since $(1,2) $ and $(2,3)$ are in $I_\mathcal{A}(P)$ but $(1,3)$ is not).